# Scala getClass match on super class/trait

Tags: class, scala, runtime, parent, match

Getting hung up on an apparently simple problem, for which there is plenty of information (too much to sift through to know what on earth the current status is).

At any rate, here goes.

```
trait _Foo
class Foo Extends _Foo with WhoAmI
trait WhoAmI {
  def who = {
    getClass match {
      case x: _Foo => "should be Foo instance, which extends _Foo"
      case _ => "why?"
    }
  }
}
val foo = new Foo
foo.who
```

have tried a guard with *classOf* and *isAssignableFrom*, as well as looping through *x.getInterfaces* (I do at least see _Foo there), but no luck in terms of a direct "lean" match.

Is this erasure "at work" or am I missing an obvious 1-liner?

If this is a duplicate of many other threads, we can close, but please point me in the right direction! ;-)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `this` instead of `getClass`:

```
this match {
```

Currently you are calling `getClass` (which returns object of `Class[T]` type) - for sure the `java.lang.Class` class does not extend your `_Foo` trait - that's "*why?*"

Comment: sorry, clarified question to reflect from where I'm trying to determine if current instance is a subclass of _Foo; namely, from another trait -- see edit

Comment: @virtualeyes: my advice is still valid after you edited your question: `getClass` -> `this`...